# Clear select parameters after GridView is rendered

Tags: c#, gridview

How can one clear SELECT parameters of an SQL Data Source after a GridView (bound to the said SQL Data Source) is rendered?

Edit:

I would like to clear the SELECT parameters of a SQL Data Source after the data which was selected by the SQL Data Source has been displayed in a GridView, but clearing the parameters in the functions associated with the GridView **DataBound** and SQL Data Source **Selected**  events results in a "Must declare the scalar variable" error, suggesting that the parameters were not defined when the SELECT query was executed. When is the appropriate time to clear the SELECT parameters?

Consider the following code, where "Selected" is associated with the SQL Data Source Selected event which is fired after a select command is completed. This results in a "Must declare the scalar variable" error.

```
static bool clearParams;

 protected void Selected(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (clearParams)
            {                
                SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear();                
                clearParams = false;
            }
        }

 protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = [a dynamically generated select command];
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add([various params are added]);

        clearParams = true; // clear params after this select command
        SqlDataSource1.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments());

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

GridView has a **DataBound** event which runs once after the data has been bound, **RowDataBound** event is running for each individual row. So you can handle the DataBound event and t will be enough